# How do I integrate this without multiplying both sides by dt?

Tags: integration

$\frac1{\sqrt{20x^2 + 10x + C}} dx/dt = 1$
How do I integrate this without doing something sketchy like multiplying both sides of the equation by $dt$?

Comment: dont think of it as multiplying by dt on both sides but as integrating w.r.t dt on both sides

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formally, if $f(x) \frac{dx}{dt}=1$ then
$$
F(x(t)) = t + K
$$
where $K$ is a constant and $F'=f$. This follows easily from the chain rule. 
In your example,
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{20 x^2+10x+C}}.
$$
Now you should compute
$$
F(x)=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{20x^2+10x+C}}.
$$
Finally, if possible, you must solve the equation $F(x(t)) = t + K$ with respect to $x(t)$.

Comment: But in this case $v(x(t)) = \sqrt{20x^2 + 10x + C}$
So $\int 1/v(x(t)) dx/dt dt$ I take $f(x) = 1/x$ therefore $=> \int f(v(x(t))) dx/dt dt$ here the derivative is of x(t) and not v(x(t)) so how would the change of variable theorem apply?

Comment: @xasthor Your comment is unclear. Anyway, the indefinite integral is not immediate, you must reduce it to some standard case. Just to give an example, this is the result if $C=1$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[1%2FSqrt[20+x^2%2B10+x%2B1],x]

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, the "reverse" chain rule or substituion would apply if it was $\int v(x(t)) dx/dt dt$ since the derivative of the function inside $v$ i.e $x(t)$ is present outside($dx/dt$)/ But when the case is $\int 1/v(x(t)) dx/dt dt$, we have to take f(x) = 1/x which gives us $\int f(v(x(t))) dx/dt dt$. How would the reversed chain rule be applicable here since the derivative present outside is of $x(t)$ and not of $v(x(t))$?

Comment: Just differentiate $F(x(t))$ with respect to $t$, and you'll see

Answer (score 0):

this looks better $$f(x)\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{k}^{x}f(x)dx$$ where $k$ is some constant of integration. now you can integrate w.r.t $t$ on both sides